# How to process the same object truth many steps in Spring Batch?

Tags: spring-batch

How to process the same object truth many steps in Spring Bath?
Gustavo Barbosa dos · há um minuto
I am querying objects from the database from JdbcPagingItemReader and what I want is:

1. Process the same object multiple times through multiple steps

Some thing like this:

```
@Bean
public Job jobValorizacao() {
  return jobBuilderFactory.get("jobValorizacao")
    .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
    .start(researchContract())
    .next(calculateInterest())
    .next(calculateArrears())
    .next(calculateFDI())
    .next(calculateXPTO())
  .build();
}
```

And when each Object passes through each Step, I want to perform update on the database.

With this control I would know in which step Job stopped, in what step I got error for each Objet, etc.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is not how Spring Batch works.  Each step is self contained within Spring Batch.  That being said, you can pass a single item through multiple `ItemProcessor` implementations within a single step.  That sounds more like what you really want. That can be achieved by passing a list of `ItemProcessor` instances to the `CompositeItemProcessor`.  From there, the delegates will be called in order.

You can read more about the `CompositeItemProcessor` in the documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/support/CompositeItemProcessor.html